# Search for products by URL in the dashboard

Tags: product, catalog

Is there a way to search for products by URL in the dashboard `(catalog->manage products)`?

Often I have the URL of the product but have trouble finding the product.

How do you proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, by default there isn't a way to search by URL. You could probably write an extension to add a column to the grid, but this raises questions like, which URL are you searching. A product can be in multiple categories, old URLs can be kept a 302'd to the correct place.

One way of doing this within core Magento would be:

1. Go to Catalog > URL Rewrite Management
2. Paste the URL into the Request Path column
3. The target path will be something like catalog/product/view/id/58156, you can use the number at the end in the Manage Products entity_id column.